# when to reshape numpy array like (3,)

Tags: python, numpy

```
 a=np.arange(3)   
 a.shape    #(3,)
 a.reshape(3,1)
```

somethings multiply, plus failed for a. 
So what's shape (3,) used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shape `(n,)` indicates a one dimensional array. If you do `reshape(3, 1)` you get a two dimensional array with one column and 3 rows.

Not sure what your question is exactly, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

reshape(n,m) is used to change the dimension of existing multi-dimensional array.
Your multiplication might have failed because of mismatch in the dimensions of the two arrays. Check if they have same dimensions or not. If not you won't be able to multiply them, it should be of same dimensions. And to get more on reshape(n,m) go to the official documentation of numpy module.

Answer (score 0):

`(3,)` stands for a tuple of one element. Because `(3)` is just a scalar `3`, not a tuple. numpy array `.shape` is always a tuple.